# "we have green light..." or "we have the green light..."?

Tags: articles

> "We have green light to print"

or

> "We have the green light to print"

Can someone please explain to me which one is better grammatically?

Comment: ***the** green light* It's a particular green light, the one that gives you permission to go.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Deadrat. It's "We have **the** green light to print." You could also say "We have **a** green light to print."

Comment: I almost agree with Deadrat and iMerchant but I think you'll find "… a green light" far more common than "… the…"